# bash関数のソースを、該当関数スコープの外部から取得する

Tags: bash

bashにおいて、任意の関数のソースファイルを取得する方法を探しています。

例えば、以下のような関数を適当なファイルに書き込んで`source`するとします。

```
somefunc () {
  echo "${BASH_SOURCE[@]}"
}
```

該当の関数それ自体においては`BASH_SOURCE`変数からソースファイルを取得できますが、外部からこれを取得する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: 別プロセスとは具体的に何ですか? `somefunc` 関数を含むファイルを `source` する `bash` プロセスとの関係を教えてください。

「ソースファイル」とは何ですか? この場合、`somefunc` 関数が記述されているファイルの名前のことを指してしますか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「別のプロセス」というのがよく分からないのですが、これは「当該関数スコープの外側」という意味でしょうか？ その場合は以下の様にして調べる事ができます。

```
## Enable debugging mode
$ shopt -s extdebug
## Show the sourced file path where a function is defined
$ declare -F ord
ord 96 /home/nemo/.bash_functions/00.sh

/home/nemo/.bash_functions/00.sh:
=================================
96: function ord {
97:   echo $(printf '%d' \'$1)
98: }
=================================
```

勘違いをしていたらすみません。

Comment: まさにその通りです。ありがとうございます。